# Cross-compile without "make"?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, wxwidgets, beagleboneblack

On Windows 10, I have downloaded the arm-none-linux-gnueabihf 9.2 toolchain from [the ARM developer site](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-a#panel3a), configured Code::Block to use it and succesfully compiled a console "Hello World" for a Beablebone Black running Debian 7.

Now, i would like to cross-compile the WXWidgets and a WxWidget "Hello World" program.

My problem is that there is no "*Make.exe" in that that toolchain, while i have always used it in the past for WxWidgets (but only for Windows); i already have all the parameters that i need.

The cross-compiling world is pretty confusing for me, so:

what should i donwload to have a "full MINGW" installation using the mentioned toolchain?

or

how can i compile the WxWidgets without a Make.exe?

Comment: you use configure and supply the `--host` and `--target` parameters to it.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate?
To use configure i should install MSYS, am i right?
doesn't configure output a new makefile?
Could you explain the details?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use gcc under Windows is to use MSYS2. It includes full Unix-like environment and will allow you to run `configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi` (or whichever triplet is used by your Beaglebone) and then `make` as usual.

Alternatively, you can use CMake, if you're more comfortable with it.

Comment: I've installed MSYS2 but i can't see the arm-none-linux-gnueabihf 9.2 using _pacman  -Ss gcc_. I need that version 'cause the Glibc version.

What should i do?